How to determine memory address for running code in VM?
Say, a code is running like this assembly on guest computer in VM environment:
mov eax,1
mov [0xBBBB],eax

I would start coding a VM with defining the RAM size and filesystem. The RAM could be sized by allocating some space in RAM and the filesystem would be easily created with commands, which are given.
In order to make VM working, I must know where the entry of memory should be, for example 0xAAAA on host computer.
When I am about coding a non-secure VM by implementing simply an allocated memory and I want to boot some code from created filesystem to RAM, how can I add every time 0xAAAA offset to the address 0xBBBB? Do I need always reading inside the executing file and map this to memory updated, like 0xAAAA + 0xBBBB? Can this be done practically in another way?

The question is too vague, you need to define your particular VM a bit better. I'm going to assume you are talking about executing native CPU code, so not like an interpreted VM (if it is, you'd just implemented memory as an array or something). So, I know of 2 basic options: 1) page table manipulation (for VMs implemented in the kernel, using either HW-assist like SLAT/nested paging, or virtualizing page table like shadow page table), or 2) JIT code rewrite for all the code so actually exected code is [0xAAA + 0xBBB].
